# multitouch slider gesture diagonal html5

Tags: touch, multi-touch, hammer.js, multitasking-gestures

My question is simple:

1- For a Multitouch table interface, with html5 on a web browser (chrome, firefox, ...)
2- I am using Hammer.js
3- I added a container (div) that you can move, drag, expand (resize)
4- Inside this "div" I added an image slider (like [royalslider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/))

### The Problem is:

When rotate this "div", I want to slide this image slider, the browser only recognize left, right, up, down. ¿But what about diagonal gesture or another one?

---> [Check this example image here](https://estebandinamarca.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/test.jpg) <----

Please Help!